# Attach Multiple disk LVM from old Xenserver to new Xenserver

Tags: lvm, xenserver

hope you can help me with this one...
We have a Xenserver 6 with 4 320 Gig disks as a one LVM Volume Group.
Suddenly past friday one disk failed and we were unable to start the server.
I have tried to access the logical volumes using sysresccd, but no success, even trying with kpartx but nothing. It seems that only 2 lvs are damaged the rest are fine an has LV status as available
So we added a new disk and installed xenserver 6 using the procedure shown here [How to Reinstall a XenServer Host and Preserve Virtual Machines on the Local Storage](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX136342)

Already introduced the new SR with xe sr-introduce with success, but when trying to create the PBD, I only can create one per SR but the repo is composed by 4 disks so I dont know how to add the PBD, or what to do next.

Any help will be apprecciated, Thanks